# ioctl() call resets file descriptor to 0

Tags: linux, ioctl

Consider the following code:

```
file_fd = open(device, O_RDWR);

if (file_fd < 0) {
    perror("open");
    return -1;
}

printf("File descriptor: %d\n", file_fd);

uint32_t DskSize;

if (ioctl(file_fd, BLKGETSIZE, &DskSize) < 0) {
    perror("ioctl");
    return -1;
}

printf("File descriptor after: %d\n", file_fd);
```

This snippet yields this:

```
File descriptor: 3
File descriptor after: 0
```

Why does my file descriptor get reset to 0? The program writes the stuff out to `stdout` instead of my block device.

This should not happen. I expect my `file_fd` to be non-zero and retain its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you smash your stack.

Since there are only two stack variables `file_fd` and `DskSize` and changing `DskSize` changes `file_fd` suggests that `DiskSize` must be `unsigned long` or `size_t` (a 64-bit value), not `uint32_t`.

Looking at [`BLKGETSIZE` implementation](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/block/ioctl.c?v=4.4#L559) confirms that the value type is `unsigned long`.

You may like to run your applications under `valgrind`, it reports this kind of errors.

Comment: While `valgrind` did not detect anything, you are right. I'm passing the address of a 4 byte integer to ioctl, and ioctl expects to write 8 bytes, but I only allocated 4.

Comment: @Gala I am surprised `valgrind` does not detect it.